# Finding the angle between a vector and a plane

Tags: calculus

> A parallelepiped which is edges are $c=(1,3,3)$, $b=(1,1,2)$, $a=(3,2,1)$
>   Find the angle between $a$ and the plane in which the face generated by $c$ and $b$ lays

I thought to find the cross product of $c$ and $b$ (the vector will be called d)and then to use $cos\theta=\frac{a\cdot d}{||a||\cdot||d||}$
and add $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because $d$ is orthogonal to the plane

Will this move be correct?

Comment: why add $\pi/2$? either $\pi/2-\theta$ or $\theta-\pi/2$

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov was not sure if to $\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Doesn't really matter, but if you want acute angle you will use 90-a or a-90, depends if a is acute

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case for
$$
\det(a,b,c) = a \cdot (b \times c)
= \lVert a \rVert \, \lVert b \times c\rVert \cos \alpha
$$
so for non-zero $a$ and $b\times c$ we get
$$ 
\cos \alpha = \frac{\det(a,b,c)}{\lVert a \rVert \, \lVert b \times c\rVert}
$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between $a$ and the normal of the face.

$\beta = \pi/2 - \alpha$ might be the angle you need.

Comment: why $\beta = \pi/2 - \alpha$ and not $\beta = \pi/2 + \alpha$?

I think I got it, it is 180=angle between $a$ and the normal+angle need+90?

Answer (score 0):

GeoGebra lets you see whats going on

The vector math used in the below worksheet screenshot can be read from the construction protocol (albeit easier with some familiarity with GeoGebra)

link to worksheet on GeoGebra: https://www.geogebra.org/m/mYCJ4BKs

The blue plane is the span of vector inputs $c, b$

I construct a orthonormal frame based on that plane - a decision has to be made on the ordering in the the Triple Vector product to match the problem description, visualization

Then vector $a$ can be doted with the orthonormal frame basis vectors, enabling a few methods of getting at the angle of interest

I choose to use the $atan$ of the the $a$ vector projection in the $c, b$ plane and the $a$ component normal to that plane

[image: GeoGebra!]